# If i choose an option in the selectbox it be must fill a other textbox

Tags: php, mysqli

If i choose a meal than come the price not in the textbox. 
What i want is that if i choose an option in the selectbox that the texbox automatic fills with the price.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
include ("connection.php");
?>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Kantine</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="logo"></div>
<div id="header">
<h1> Change or Delete meals</h1>
</div>
<div id="menu"></div>
<div id="content">    
<?php
echo '<select name="Meals">';
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT meal, price FROM meals") ;

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
  {
  echo "<option value=\""."\">" . $row['meal']."</option>\n";
  echo "<br />";
  }
  echo '</select>'; 
  echo '<input type="text" value="' . $row['price'] . '"/>';  
mysqli_close($con);
?>    
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is not suitable for client side scripting. What you want depend on the user choice on the browser side, therefore you'll need Javascript for that. If that action requires a database connection then you may want to use AJAX to connect to a PHP script and get the query results.

Take a look at the [jQuery](http://jquery.com) framework and specifically to the [ajax section](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) of it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried escaping the " in your first echo? Also some of your html can be moved out of the php section, and you dont need linebreaks between option elements. And mixing single and double quotes is a sure way to get into trouble. Be consistent.

```
<select name="Meals">
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT meal, price FROM meals") ;

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
  {
      echo "<option value=\"". $row['meal'] . "\">" . $row['meal'] . "</option>";
  }

echo "<input type=\"text\" value=\"" . $row['price'] . "\"/>";  
mysqli_close($con);
?>   
</select>
```